# Create cross-tabulation of most frequent value of string variable and sort by frequency

Tags: r, sorting, tabulate

I have a sample dataset:

```
df <- data.frame(category = c("A", "A", "B", "C", "C", "D", "E", "C", "E", "A", "B", "C", "B", "B", "B", "D", "D", "D", "D", "B"), year = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1))
```

and would like to create a cross-tabulation of `year` and `category` such that only the 3 most frequent categories are in the table and also sorted by total number of occurences:

```
    1 2 3
  B 4 2 0
  D 1 2 2
  C 2 1 1
```

Using something like

```
df %>% 
  add_count(category) %>% 
  filter(n %in% tail(sort(unique(n)),3)) %>% 
  arrange(desc(n)) %>% {table(.$category, .$year)}
```

will filter for the three most occurring categories but leave the table unsorted

```
    1 2 3
  B 4 2 0
  C 2 1 1
  D 1 2 2
```

Comment: `table(df)` something like this?

Comment: yes, but ```table(df)``` will give me the whole dataset and also sorted alphabetically and not by frequency

Comment: Maybe you look at the `tabyl` function from the `janitor` package

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should give you what you want.

```r
# Make a table
df.t <- table(df)
# Order by top occurrences (sum over margin 1)
df.t <- df.t[order(apply(df.t, 1, sum), decreasing=TRUE),]
# Keep top 3 results
df.t <- df.t[1:3,]
```

Output:

```
        year
category 1 2 3
       B 4 2 0
       D 1 2 2
       C 2 1 1
```

Comment: `(s<-table(df))[order(-rowSums(s))[1:3],]`

Comment: Thanks for that succinct expression @onyambu. I didn't realise it was possible to define and access an object on a single line. That's really neat!

Comment: Yours is clear and better . +1 ;)

Comment: You could also use `df.t[order(rowSums(df.t), decreasing=TRUE),]` :)

Answer (score 1):

It's not elegent solution using base R but it works

```
result <- as.data.frame.matrix(table(df))
result$sum <- rowSums(result)
result <- result[order(-result$sum),]
result <- result[1:3,]
result$sum <- NULL

  1 2 3
B 4 2 0
D 1 2 2
C 2 1 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd want to arrange by the rowsums **after** creating table. If you want to stay (more) within `tidyverse`, e.g.:

```r
df |>
  janitor::tabyl(category, year) |>
  arrange(desc(rowSums(across(where(is.numeric))))) |>
  head(3)
```

Here with `janitor::tabyl()`, but you could also use `dplyr::tally()` and `tidyr::pivot_longer()` directly or do `df |> table() |> as.data.frame.matrix()` like @Adamm.